# How to replace file_get_contents() with a Wordpress Filesystem call

Tags: php, filesystem, wp-filesystem

I'm using the PHP `file_get_contents()` function to retrieve and echo the contents of an SVG-file.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/Search_Glyph.svg' ); ?>
```

I checked the theme with the [Wordpress.org theme checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) and I am currently resolving all the issues. One of the issues is the use of `file_get_contents`.

It gives me the following warning:

```
WARNING: file_get_contents was found in the file header.php File operations should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls.
```

I tried finding information about the `$wp_filesystem` thing, but there is very little information available and even less examples (to be honest, I'm not totally sure if that's the correct function to use).

How can I use a Wordpress function to retrieve a file and echo the contents of it in a PHP-file?

I'm really at loss what I should do with this. All help is very  much appreciated!

Comment: What is the theme checker you're using?

Comment: Just replace `file_get_contents($path)` with `WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents($path)`

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm using the [Wordpress.org theme checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) to identify common mistakes. Ultimately it's for Envato, and this plugin gives me an idea of the quality and the pain points.

Comment: Hi @SabbirHasan thanks for the suggestion! I changed it to `<?php echo WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/Search_Glyph.svg'); ?>` but when I try to save it, it gives an error (I added it via the theme editor). The error is: (1)

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Filesystem_Direct' not found in wp-content/themes/ambition-theme/header.php:133
Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/template.php(723): require_once()
#1 wp-includes/template.php(672): load_template('/home/u36816p32...', true)
#2 wp-includes/general-template.php(41): locate_template(Array, true)
#3 wp-content/themes/ambition-theme/home.php(1): get_header()
#4 wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/u36816p32...')
#5 wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/u36816p32...')
#6 /home/u36816p32xxxx/domains/creativec` (2)

Comment: UPDATE: I added this `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';` to my functions.php and now it works. @SabbirHasan if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that as an answer now.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include information rather than putting it in the comments? The theme checker is to make sure it has everything it needs to pass the .org theme hosting requirements, you should use PHP Codesniffer with the WordPress ruleset if you want to check code quality

Comment: @TomJNowell I updated the question. Thanks for suggesting the PHP Codesniffer, I'll certainly look into that as well. I use the .org checker because that was a plugin and easy to install and it helped me identify common problems (think of things like not adding theme support for title tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add this two line to your functions.php file. Sorry I forgot to mention about this earlier.

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';
```

now you can use `WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents($path)` instead of `file_get_contents($path)`

**Update: 20 July 2023**

After some digging it's safe to say that you should use the file system like this:

```
$filesystem = new WP_Filesystem_Direct( true );

// Now use it like this

$filesystem->get_contents($path)
```

All available methods can be found here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php/

Comment: Non-static method WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents() cannot be called statically

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 01**

```
$wp_filesystem = new \WP_Filesystem_Direct(null);
$svg= $wp_filesystem->get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/Search_Glyph.svg');
```

**Solution 02**

```
$remote_svg_file = wp_remote_get(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/Search_Glyph.svg');
$svg_content = wp_remote_retrieve_body($remote_svg_file );
```

Comment: Hi @EjazULHaq thanks for the solution! I already got an answer from SabbirHasan in the comments and I asked him to post it as answer. If he does it, I'll mark that as correct. Otherwise I'll mark your answer as correct next week. I did upvote it. Thanks! Ralph

Comment: Thanks @ralphsmit

Comment: Note that solution 2 will involve a HTTP request, making it very slow, and on a lot of systems means it'll go out on to the open web then loop back on itself. Also this answer doesn't explain anything, edit it to explain what it does so it isn't just copy pasta otherwise it isn't useful for new developers

Comment: Solution 1 will not work when the project uses Composer with PSR-4 autoloading, as `WP_Filesystem_Direct` does not conform to PSR-4 requirements.

Comment: @MarcioDuarte, I have updated so now it will work with PSR-4 and it is a standard solution that you should add \ before the class name when you are calling any call without namespace in the PSR-4.